# Is it possible to use php-fpm with Nginx reverse proxy front end of Apache

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy, php

I was trying to use Nginx reverse proxy at front end of Apache since they work great together and produce acceptable page load time. Since php5 is involved in this process, I was wondering if I can replace it with php-fpm so that the speed would be a lot faster and the performance would get much better...

I could so far make Nginx work php-fpm and Apache with php-fpm, but can't make php-fpm work with Nginx reverse proxy... any idea if that is possible??

You may ask me why I want to use Nginx reverse proxy over Nginx +php-fpm!! Ok, the answer is very simple. I want Apache to handles the dynamic content and Nginx handles the static contents, and this is a big reason why...

So now I want to know if php-fpm can be involved in this process or not!

**Update #1**

Is it better to have both Apache+php-fpm and Nginx+php-fpm running separately. Then feed Apache content with Nginx static files... is that dump to do or what???

Comment: do you have a lot of complicated htaccess files? if not you can replace apache entirely with nginx and fpm

Comment: not really... all simple ones.

Comment: wait, how about the connections to the server when serving many php pages!! would Nginx+php-fpm be as powerful handling php as Apache?

Comment: as a starting point, you can configure nginx to just proxy every thing unconfigured to apache, then one by one configure each server to just proxy dynamic files to apache, then migrate the htaccess files to nginx rewrites, at the end you'll be free to uninstall or at least shutdown apache.

Comment: ok, if I shutdown Apache, then how would I server the dynamic php contents??

Comment: right now I would say not, but if you migrated every thing it would work just fine.

Comment: can you explain more because it is a little unclear. what is the idea behind shutting Apache in this case?